# How to change the number of significant figures in a Matlab tree

Tags: matlab, tree

I have made a regression tree, but Matlab shows numbers with 6 significant figures. The tree is very dense, and I don't need such a high precision, which makes it hard to read. 
How can I change it to 3 figures for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `vpa`

e.g.

```
vpa([114.234 0.0013452],3)= [ 114.0, 0.00135]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following

while printing something you may use

```
a=2.335444444444
sprintf ('%.2f',a) % I want to print 2 significant digits of a only
```

Output

```
ans =

2.34
```

Comment: Is it possible to give a snapshot of your figure along with relevant code?

Comment: Does not work in my case. Please, explain the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the [format](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/format.html) to something of your taste (`help format`)

You may be interested in:

```
format bank
```

or

```
format short
```

Comment: format doesn't appear to change the data when you call view(t) where t is a tree...